# How to count the number of peaks with some certain conditions?

Tags: excel, matlab, graph, threshold

I have a graph in the screenshot, and each peak corresponds to one footstep while walking. Thus, I want to count the total number of peaks (which are higher than 4 in this situation).

How can I do this, in Excel, MATLAB or any software?

[image: Screenshot of chart with peaks]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be useful if you could provide more information - see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for an idea of what type of information would help us answer your question. For example, what is your input? Do you have the data that was used to produce the graph, or do you just have the image of the graph? If you have the data, what format is it in? Etc.

Comment: Do you mean you need to read in the pixel information and count the peaks? Otherwise it looks like a periodic function with (I ball-parked) a period of approx. 0.6. Just divide the length on x-axis by 0.6 and you have the number of peaks.

Comment: Oh it's actually a helpful trick for me. Thank you very much.